# Creating a matrix from a list of attributes

Tags: php, python, ruby, matrix, data-analysis

I have a CSV with a list of items, and each has a series of attributes attached:

```
"5","coffee|peaty|sweet|cereal|cream|barley|malt|creosote|sherry|sherry|manuka|honey|peaty|peppercorn|chipotle|chilli|salt|caramel|coffee|demerara|sugar|molasses|spicy|peaty"
"6","oil|lemon|apple|butter|toffee|treacle|sweet|cola|oak|cereal|cinnamon|salt|toffee"
```

"5" and "6" are both item IDs and unique in the file.

Ultimately, I want to create a matrix demonstrating how many times in the document each attribute was mentioned in the same row with every other attribute. E.g.:

```
        peaty    sweet    cereal    cream    barley ...
coffee    1       2         2         1        1
oil       0       1         0         0        0
```

Note that I'd prefer to reduce duplicates: i.e., "peaty" isn't both a column and a row.

The original database is essentially a key-value store (A table with columns "itemId" and "value") -- I can reformat the data if it helps.

Any idea how I'd do this with Python, PHP or Ruby (Whichever is easiest)? I get the feeling Python can probably do this the easiest of the bunch but I'm missing something fairly basic and/or crucial (I'm just starting to do data analysis with Python).

Thanks!

**Edit:** In response to the (somewhat unhelpful) "What have you tried" comment, here's what I'm currently working with (Don't laugh, my Python is terrible):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

matrix = {}

with open("field.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        attribs = row[1].split("|")
        for attrib in attribs:
            if attrib not in matrix:
                matrix[attrib] = {}
            for attrib2 in attribs:
                if attrib2 in matrix[attrib]:
                    matrix[attrib][attrib2] = matrix[attrib][attrib2] + 1 
                else:
                    matrix[attrib][attrib2] = 1
print matrix
```

The output is a big, unsorted dictionary of terms, likely with a lot of duplication between the rows and columns. If I use pandas and replace the "print matrix" line with the following...

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame(matrix).T.fillna(0)
print df
```

I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 195 entries, acacia to zesty
Columns: 195 entries, acacia to zesty
dtypes: float64(195)
```

...Which leads me to think I'm doing something rather wrong.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: peaty has to be both a row and a column, otherwise how do you compare it to both sweet and coffee ?

Comment: @njzk2 I guess that makes sense. I'm ultimately wanting to plug it into a cord diagram and am just not wanting a cord to loop back onto itself. See: http://circos.ca/guide/tables/img/guide-table-large.png

Comment: `In response to the (somewhat unhelpful) "What have you tried" comment`...? Unhelpful to who? You're asking us to donate time to help you. We ask that you show us what you've tried, and give us the information we need to give reasonable answers to an open-ended question that could be considered "not-constructive" by some here.

Comment: @theTinMan -- Won't get into it here, though I do plan on eventually writing a blogpost about my thoughts on it (In short, it's the SO equivalent of telling people to RTFM).

Comment: Then I'm sure you'll want to include these links: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/, http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/how-can-i-get-answers-fast, http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/,

Comment: @theTinMan -- Thank you for those links, I most assuredly will.

Comment: Notice that the first in the list is by [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), one of SO's major power-users.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes, I noticed (Quite familiar with Jon Skeet's work). And the third in that list is by Eric S. Raymond, author of "The Cathedral and The Bazaar". It is a quite a good list — again, thanks for taking the time to post those.

Comment: @aendrew : while I appreciate that it can seem a bit abrupt to comment 'what have you tried', you'll notice that it leads you to add details to your question that are quite helpful in understanding what you are trying to acheive, to understand what you are struggling with, and to see that you are not just looking to a ready-made solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this with an undirected graph, where the frequency is the edge weight. Then you can generate the matrix quite easily by looping through each vertex, where each edge weight represents how many times each element occurred with another.

Graph docs: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes.graph.html

Starter code:

```
import csv
import itertools
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

reader = csv.reader(open('field.csv', "rb"))
for row in reader:
  row_elements = row[1].split("|")
  combinations = itertools.combinations(row_elements, 2)
  for (a, b) in combinations:
    if G.has_edge(a, b):
      G[a][b]['weight'] += 1
    else:
      G.add_edge(a, b, weight=1)

print(G.edges(data=True))
```

Edit: woah see if this does everything for ya http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/linalg.html#module-networkx.linalg.graphmatrix

Comment: Interesting idea -- am now playing around in Gephi a bit. Looking forward to your update!

Comment: my understanding of your code is that your graph is actually directed, but for each edge (a, b, w) there is an edge (b, a, w) (which can be a representation of an undirected graph)

Comment: @njzk2, I've honestly never used `networkx` so I'm not sure how the inner mechanics work. looked like a good python graph lib tho

Comment: Networkx looks pretty cool, have played around with outputting the graph using the various functions on that page. My lack of math background is starting to become evident here, though -- which of those is closest to what I'm wanting (Disregarding the "no duplicates" request)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Counter with the tuple composed of the 2 strings as key. Off course you'll have every combination in double, but so far I don't see how to avoid this:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

counter = Counter()
with open("field.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        attribs = row[1].split("|")
        for cmb in itertools.combinations(attribs, 2):
            counter[cmb] += 1
```

Comment: That seems pretty close to what I'm wanting -- is there a Python function to output it as a matrix like I have in the question? It seems like NumPy is what people use for this, but I'm not at all sure how to correctly transform your output into something it can use. Again, bit of a Python newbie. Thanks!

Comment: i don't know much about numpy yet, but i guess putting the counter in a table form shouldn't be too hard. you can get unique items by creating a set() of the first item of each key, then it should be a matter of enumerating them, likely using itertools again. I'll see tomorow if i can drop an example